# Not able to install 'pip3' in Ubuntu

Tags: python, pip

$ sudo apt install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package python3-pip is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3-pip' has no installation candidate

Comment: try running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: done but same error

Comment: try https://askubuntu.com/a/250834

Comment: I once had a similar problem with `sudo apt install python3-pip` ("unable to locate package python3-pip") and it was fixed by adding the `universe` repository to apt: `sudo add-apt-repository universe && sudo apt update && sudo apt install python3-pip`. Maybe this also works for you.

Comment: thnkx
- @NiklasMertsch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first procedure you followed is correct

`sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip`
But before installing try to update using command

`sudo apt-get update`

If first did not work then you can also do this using curl

```
curl "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "get-pip.py"
python3 get-pip.py --user
```

if above not work:

```
curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python
```

Then to verify installation try

`pip3 --help`

For checking version :

`pip3 --version`

Comment: if this works for you dont forget to upvote and accept answer.

Comment: i tried "sudo add-apt-repository universe"
and then "sudo apt update && sudo apt install python3-pip"
and it worked